# help identifying black component

Tags: components

Can anyone tell me what this component is?
This is a hall effect ignition pickup on a lawn mower engine (Onan P220).
Thanks[image]

Comment: That board's seen better days...

Comment: It looks like a fuse.

Comment: Looks like a wire-wound resistor that burned off its outer coating.  Isolate one end and measure it.

Comment: Or the [inside of a carbon film resistor](https://www.google.com/search?q=inside+of+carbon+film+resistor).

Answer (score 3):

It was or perhaps still is a resistor. Perhaps oxide film type. If it is not damaged, you may be able to measure it. Power rating could be estimated from the dimensions.

Looks like you've removed potting and possibly that has taken the outer layer off. And maybe sawed through an electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: It was potted, yes.  I removed the potting, but the device in question was not harmed in the potting removal (the larger resistor above it was damaged, but I was able to get the color code from it).  The black part appears, as best I can tell, exactly like it looked when soldered to the board.

Comment: +12V is supplied to this part via the red wire to the right.  Power flows through it to the diode, through the board via to the large resistor located above.  It then travels from the large resistor to a hall effect sensor.  The hall triggers a D1071 NPN transistor.  So the output is typically +12V.  When the magnet passes the hall the transistor is fired and the output changes to 1V, thereby firing the coil which fires the spark plugs.